# Highcharts line chart - do not display the line

Tags: javascript, highcharts

This requirement may sound bit weird but unfortunately It is the requirement which I have to fulfill. In Highcharts Line chart, can we hide the line and just display the points? Something like the following link:     8bdovxn4

Using the above fiddler link, I have set the line width to 0. But on hover It displays the line. Is It possible to hide the line on hover too?

Comment: So you want a [scatter chart](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/scatter-chart)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `lineWidthPlus` property on hover state to 0. As an alternative, you can use `scatter` series type: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0ke4or2z/

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        lineWidth: 0,
        states: {
            hover: {
                lineWidthPlus: 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/614fr8oj/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.states.hover.lineWidthPlus